# How do I change the cursor scroll behavior for an EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I just made a super basic test where all I did was take the hello world sample template and add a multiline text object. The text object is at the bottom of the screen. When I enter multiple lines of text, and then move the cursor around, the entire screen scrolls downward, and so the soft keyboard starts to cover up the text box. I'm trying (in a more complex app but having this same issue, so hence using a basic test case) to have the behavior match the default messaging app: if you move the cursor, it doesn't pan the entire viewport, and will only scroll the text object as appropriate. It's easier to explain visually.

[image]

Here we have 3 lines, I'm about to scroll upward (doesn't matter if I use arrow keys or use the little teardrop selector thing).

[image]

Here I've grabbed the little selector teardrop thing and moved up 2 lines: notice that the entire window has scrolled down. I don't want that behavior. What I'm looking for is this from the default messaging app:

[image]

Notice how moving the cursor does not scroll the viewport. It doesn't scroll at all. If I had too much text to fit, it would instead just scroll the contents of the edit text as appropriate, and not scroll anything else.

How do i get that behavior? In case it matters, for this simple test here's what the layout looks like.

[image]

Edit: as per request, I'm posting the xml and java. Note that this is just the default Android Studio hello world project with an edittext added. 
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jeffw.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jeffw.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.705" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="109dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="11dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jeffw.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: try : <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: Share your xml code as well as java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this behavior you should add this  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and  `android:isScrollContainer="true"` to your activity in manifest file.

For more details you can review developers documents. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

**Update**

Update this to your manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`.. I have used RelativeLayout instead of `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` and it is working fine for me.

Comment: I added that to the <activity> section in AndroidManifest.xml and it didn't change the behavior, sadly.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please find updated information and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I got it to work but slightly differently than your answer. I had to set isScrollContainer="false" (or actually just not specifying it at all was fine too) but other than that it worked. The key was changing the layout to android.widget.RelativeLayout from android.support.design.widget.ConstraintLayout, and using that adjustResize|stateHidden instead of adjustPan. I actually was able to just use adjustResize as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// SCROLL VIEW HACK
// BOGUS
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView .setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
scrollView .setFocusable(false);
scrollView .setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
scrollView .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I think it helps you.

Comment: I tried placing that at the end of OnCreate in MainActivity but the app just crashes because "scrollView" is null.

Comment: @Architekt I think you could something like editText.findViewById()

Comment: Ah, thanks @VVB. I tried it and it just prevents the editText from getting any focus so I can't type and enter text into it.